# JSOUP HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, google-search, google-search-api

I tried to scrape the google news content from a specific range of time from 1/1/2016 to 31/12/2016.

Originally, this code worked before. After running several times, it appears the **http** error.

I don't know whether I set the *userclient* incorrect or it is blocked by **GOOGLE** ?

*> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://www.google.com/search%253Fq%253Dstackoverflow%2526tbm%253Dnws%2526tbs%253Dcdr%2525253A1%2525252Ccd_min%2525253A5%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2525252Ccd_max%2525253A6%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2526start%253D0&q=EgTKLTckGKH5hsQFIhkA8aeDS-3IYZmr41q-m4rIMh7Uw7vC3wdLMgNyY24
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:679)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:676)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
            at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:36)*

## Code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String search = "stackoverflow";

        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String news="&tbm=nws";

  String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news+"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016";
     String userAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"; 
     int numberOfResultpages = 10; // grabs first two pages of search results
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {
       Document document = Jsoup.connect(string).userAgent(userAgent) .data("start",""+i).get();
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");

        for (Element link : links) {

            String title = link.text();
            String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

            if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                continue; // Ads/news/etc.
            }
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        }
}
    }
```

Comment: I've ran your code as is and got urls like this - `http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/stack-overflow-announces-adrianna-burrows-as-chief-marketing-officer-300262067.html` which is in a very different format than you expect. Which Jsoup version are you using? mine is 1.10.1

Comment: @TDG I think I have processed a soft ban from GOOGLE. After half hour , the error is gone .But appear this error`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
 at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:43)`

Comment: @Monchhichi Looks like you'll need to check the indexOf() calls to see whether or not the absolute URL you're looking at is formatted as you're expecting. From the exception, it sounds like in some cases it isn't.

Comment: That's exectly what I'm getting. Print the url to the console (right after the line `String url = ...` and you'll see that the resopnse is not as you expect, so it cannot find = or &.